# OTRS migration old server to new server

Tags: mysql, database-migration, otrs

I'm doing [OTRS](http://www.otrs.com/try/) migration from my old server to new server, at the same time I want it to be done version upgrading. Everything so far smoothly, one big issue is, users cannot log in after migrating database. The following are some steps I done so far, please correct me anything I missed out.

(1) My fresh new Windows Server 2008 had installed OTRS 3.3.4 ( old server is running OTRS 2.4.7)

(2) Copied over those files and replace them in new server.
        - OTRS\Kernel\Config.pm
        - OTRS\Kernel\Config\GenericAgent.pm
        - OTRS\Kernel\Config\Files\ZZZAuto.pm

(3) Dropped the new OTRS 3.3.4 database

(4) Imported the old OTRS 2.4.7 database to new server running with MySQL

(5) set MySQL database permission, roles and schema privileges that same like old server

But after those steps done, failed to log in from web interface. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy accross the config files, database and all files.

It is hard to tell what went wrong along the way but make sure to run the database upgrade scripts.

Since the upgrade is quite a big step there would have been several changes done to the major and minor releases of otrs. 
for every minor release there will be database scripts to run. instructions to do so will be found in a file named UPGRADE.

I would suggest trying to migrate the otrs to yur new server using the same otrs version. if all works fine you can try to then upgrade to later versions. at least this way you will eliminate the source of your error. 
Also if you ahve some errors in the logs they might help you detect the source of your agony

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

OTRS 3.2 introduced the `sessions`-table. And without a place to store your session, OTRS is most likely to just fail ;-)

Check your database if you have it - if not, you probably missed some of the database-schema-updates...